# Degree unicode showing as Question Mark

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

The following code shows up as a question mark instead of a degree sign:

```
var airF = Math.round(Number(MDTMOBILE.RWISWeather[i].AirTemp)) + "\u00B0" + "F";
$('.tempTable').find('td').eq(4).text(airF);
var relHum = Math.round(MDTMOBILE.RWISWeather[i].RH) + "%";
$('.tempTable').find('td').eq(5).text(relHum);
var dewF = Math.round(Number(MDTMOBILE.RWISWeather[i].Dewpoint)) + "\u00B0" + "F";
$('.tempTable').find('td').eq(6).text(dewF);
```

It displays as:
Temp    RH  Dew
54�F    38%     29�F

Am I using the wrong unicode?  "\u00B0"

Comment: What's your page's charset?

Comment: page's charset =    <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: Turns out my script minify process removed the \u00B0 and replace with a degree symbol, change the min script and it works fine.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: That means your javascript is not served as unicode. Otherwise replacing with a degree symbol would do no harm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation `"\u00B0"` is a correct way to use the degree sign in a character literal. But you can also write the character directly, `"°"`, provided that character encoding has been selected and announced properly, as it should.

If you see “�” on a web page, the most common reason is that the character encoding of an HTML document is windows-1252 (or iso-8859-1) but the declared encoding is utf-8. However, in this case, such problems should not arise, because the string is generated in JavaScript, and JavaScript and the DOM internally use UTF-16 for characters data, no matter what the document’s encoding is. To analyze what goes wrong, I think we need a self-contained demo that reproduces the problem, and/or a URL of a demo.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your page is not unicode, but even then you can use `.html('&#x00b0;')` instead — I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your jQuery is on a JSP page, you can try this

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```